# Lint multiple directories with stylelint

Tags: sass, glob, package.json, stylelint

I'm trying to lint more than one directory at once with stylelint.

In my `package.json` file I have:

```js
"scripts": {
  "lint": "stylelint 'pages/**/*.scss', 'global/components/**/*.scss' ; exit 0"
},
```

If I remove either `'pages/**/*.scss'` or `'global/components/**/*.scss'`, I can lint one of the directories.

Is it possible to lint 2 at once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to lint 2 at once?

Yes.

stylelint expects a single glob pattern, but you can construct a glob pattern that matches more than one directory. For example:

```
{global/components,pages}/**/*.scss
```

And in the context of your example:

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "stylelint '{global/components,pages}/**/*.scss'; exit 0"
},
```

stylelint supports [these glob features](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch#features) and you can test your glob patterns using [globtester.com](http://www.globtester.com)